# How can I compute the probability of a union of intersections?

Tags: probability

How can I compute the probability of a union of intersections? For example, if A, B, and C are independent events,
$$\Pr((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)) = ? $$

Is it $\Pr((A∩B)∪(A∩C)∪(B∩C)) = \Pr(A) \cdot \Pr(B) + \Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(C) + \Pr(B)\cdot \Pr(C)$ ? Feels like this is too simple and I have to subtract something...

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  $A\cap B\cup A\cap C$ is not valid notation.  Do you mean $(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$?  Or do you mean $A\cup (B\cap A)\cup C$?  These are different outcomes.  As such, you should never mix intersection and union without proper parentheses.

Comment: As for if you mean $\Pr((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C))$, yes that expands via inclusion exclusion out to be $\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(A\cap C)+\Pr(B\cap C) - \Pr((A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C)) - \Pr((A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C))-\Pr((A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C)) + \Pr((A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C))$ which simplifies.  In the event they are mutually independent, you can write in terms of $\Pr(A),\Pr(B),\Pr(C)$ themselves as well.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I corrected my notation. Could you explain what you mean by "write in terms of $Pr(A),Pr(B),Pr(C)$"?

Comment: I meant that rather than $\Pr(A\cap B)$ you could write as $\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B)$, but that is allowed only when $A$ and $B$ were actually independent, and if they weren't then this wouldn't have been allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are interested in
$$P((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C));$$
without the brackets this is ambiguous. That is precisely the event that at least two of $A,B,C$ occur.

Now $P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)+P(B\cap C)$ is not the same as this probability, since the events overlap - this would count $A\cap B\cap C$ three times (indeed, it's easy to see that this sum can be greater than $1$). Thus the actual answer is
$$P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)+P(B\cap C)-2P(A\cap B\cap C);$$
if the events are independent you can replace these with products as usual.

Comment: Do you know a generalization for this? E.g., I've been trying to compute the probability of at least three of five events ($A, B, C, D, E$) occuring based on this, but don't come up with the correct result (which I know from simulating data).

Comment: @Robn if you sum the triple intersections, that counts every quadruple intersection $4$ times, so you have to subtract $3$ times the sum of quadruple intersections. Now you have counted the quintuple intersection $-5$ times (you counted it $10$ times in the triples, and then $-3\times 5$ times in the quadruples) so you have to add it in again $6$ times. So it is $(P(A\cap B \cap C)+\dots)-3(P(A\cap B \cap C\cap D)+\dots)+6P(A\cap B\cap C\cap D\cap E)$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me, which area of math this is? I'd like to understand how you calculate that quadruple intersections are counted 4 times and want to read up on this (but don't know which key words to use searching explanations).

Comment: @Robn I guess you would say it is combinatorics - it's closely related to the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

$\Pr(X\cup Y\cup Z) = \Pr(X)+\Pr(Y)+\Pr(Z)-\Pr(X\cap Y)-\Pr(X\cap Z)-\Pr(Y\cap Z)+\Pr(X\cap Y\cap Z)$

This is true even when $X,Y,Z$ can be written as intersections or unions of other events or something even more complicated.